# Sharepoint 2007 Column character limit

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

We are having problems with uploading very large character strings using the .asmx webservices to different lists we have on a site (300000 characters about). I haven't been able to find the character limit for a Sharepoint 2007 column in a list, but know its around 2gb on SP 2013. Does anyone happen to know this number or limit?

Comment: 300k chars or 50k works? Maybe that needs to be in a document rather than a field? http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=300000+characters&lk=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the column.  Each column can be configured for a certain length.  For example, the default for a text field is 255 characters, but can be configured by you when you create the column. I believe multi-line text fields can contain up to 65k.  You 300,000 character strings may be outside any of the available SharePoint fields.